# Replicating ESP32-CAM

Tags: esp32, camera, esp32cam

I need help/guidance on how to interface a camera module like an ov2640 to ESP32-S3.is 10 pin enough? because on the esp32-cam it looks like the camera use around 16pin (I'm short of pins). btw i know very little close to nothing on how to connect an camera module like ov2640 to ESP32-S3 and the software/programming. but I'm here to learn more. it's a little hard to find information about this (i wish i had a mentor/teacher).

**i don't think it's a duplicate. the "NTSC/PAL Camera for ESP32", is asking is it possible to use NTSC/PAL camera with esp32-s3. while on this one, i just asked how to interface a camera module with CSI/CPI like an ov2640 to esp32-s3. basically i asked how to replicate ESP32-CAM in my design.**

Comment: This is a duplicate of [NTSC/PAL Camera for ESP32](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/702730/ntsc-pal-camera-for-esp32). If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: i don't think it's a duplicate. the "NTSC/PAL Camera for ESP32", is asking is it possible to use NTSC/PAL camera with esp32-s3. while on this one, i just asked how to interface a camera module with CSI/CPI like an ov2640 to esp32-s3. basically i asked how to replicate ESP32-CAM in my design.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need more than 10 pins, as far as I can tell:

- 8 parallel data lanes, which you will have to connect to pounds of the same gpio bank if you want anything like working dma transfers
- 1 clock pin, generated by the Microcontroller
- 2 pins for the I2C control interface

And if I remember correctly, there's a few other reset and synchronization pins.

I think you're underestimating the difficulty of this. Maybe start looking up the data sheet of your camera module (it can easily if not officially be found using a search engine of your choice), and go through the descriptions of the pins. Take notes on the function of each pin! If you have a question on the function of a pin, which you can't solve by doing reasonable own research, feel welcome to ask here.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. i have 10 pin that's empty, 2 pin is already used for i2c, so i think i can put my camera i2c line to that pin (on the same bus). and i still have 4 jtag pin that i can use, but as far as i know i need to burn some "e-fuse" which honestly i don't understand on what is e-fuse and how to "burn it". also, do you maybe know generally the pins on ov2640 camera module that already have and flexible ftp connector?